# Downgrade code of HttpClient .NET 4.5 to .NET 4.0

Tags: c#, .net-4.0, httpclient, .net-4.5, async-await

I have this code that is working fine in .NET 4.5.

```
var handler = new HttpClientHandler();
handler.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
handler.PreAuthenticate = true;
handler.ClientCertificateOptions = ClientCertificateOption.Automatic;

var client = new HttpClient(handler);
client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:22678/");
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(
                    new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

var loginBindingModel = new LoginBindingModel { Password = "test01", UserName = "test01" };

var response = await client.PostAsJsonAsync("api/Account/Login", loginBindingModel);
                response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode(); // Throw on error code.
                tokenModel = await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<TokenModel>();
```

Now I have to do the same thing in .NET 4.0.

But I am facing two problems I do not know how to resolve them.

1. In .NET 4.0. method `client.PostAsJsonAsync` does not exist.
2. The existing method is `client.PostAsync` and it needs `HttpContext`.

[image]

I do request within WPF client... Guys, I have no clue what I can do to archive the same functionality...

Please, help!

Comment: [HttpClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpclient%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is new to 4.5 so you can't downgrade it, you will need to use a diffrent class.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain Thank you! Could u suggest what do I have to use, please?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Suggest using the BCL / async / "Microsoft HTTP Client Libraries" helper projects to "supplement" .Net 4.0 with equivalent functionality to .Net 4.5  (Can find the latest versions in the NuGet package manager.)
See the following link for more info:  http://www.nuget.org/packages/microsoft.bcl.async
(Note: you can get support for http client via same basic mechanism)

Comment: I know but I need to send JSON string that is what I do here client.PostAsJsonAsync("api/Account/Login", loginBindingModel);

Comment: I believe we are using the "Microsoft HTTP Client Libraries" Microsoft.Net.Http ver 2.2.18 (via NuGet) in order to use client.PostAsJsonAsync from app targeting .net 4.0

Comment: I just installed https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Net.Http and it does not have PostAsJsonAsync  at all. Are you sure it has that method? Take a look at the image I just posted in my answer.

Comment: I just double-checked one of the projects in our solution that targets .Net 4.0 and calls client.PostAsJsonAsync()  Looks like it is handled via an extension method.  I suspect you may need the line using System.Net.Http.Formatting in the module making the call.  (Are you using VS 2010 - One of the notes says VS2010 not supported.)

Comment: Thanks for comments! Could u help me how I can use System.Net.Http.Formatting in that case I am not sure...

Comment: After adding "Microsoft HTTP Client Libraries" to your project via NuGet simply make sure that "using System.Net.Http;" and "using System.Net.Http.Formatting;" are at the top of your source module that has the client.PostAsJsonAsync() call in it.  (Email me if you still do not see it)

Comment: System.Net.Http.Formatting does not seem to be  in the "Microsoft HTTP Client Libraries"

Answer (score 4):

Just for someone who is looking for the same .NET 4.0 pure solution I found that code working fine. But It does not have `ASYNC/AWAIT` thing that should be implemented as well. Anyway it is working exactly the same way as my code in the question.

```
var webAddr = "http://localhost:22678/api/Account/Login";
var httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(webAddr);
httpWebRequest.ContentType = "application/json; charset=utf-8";
httpWebRequest.Method = "POST";

using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(httpWebRequest.GetRequestStream()))
{
      var loginBindingModel = new WebAPILoginBindingModel { Password = "test01", UserName = "test01" };
      var myJsonString = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(loginBindingModel);
                    streamWriter.Write(myJsonString);
                    streamWriter.Flush();
}

var httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)httpWebRequest.GetResponse();
using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(httpResponse.GetResponseStream()))
{
    var result = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
}
```

If you want to use use ASYNC/AWAIT for .NET 4.0 you have to install [Microsoft.BCL](http://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Bcl/)  dll and use **async versions of HttpClient** as well.

Answer (score 2):

Even after installing the following packages i got other errors.

`Install-Package Microsoft.Net.Http`

`Install-Package System.Net.Http.Formatting.Extension`

Turns out `Install-Package System.Net.Http.Formatting.Extension` installs version of system.net that does not support dot net 4. So I has to stick to `PostAsync` and create an httpContent object from my custom object.

So

`PostAsJsonAsync("api/Account/Login", loginBindingModel)`

Becomes (Note i used json.net [here](https://www.nuget.org/packages/newtonsoft.json/) )

```
public  HttpContent CreateHttpContent(object data)
        {  
            return new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
        }
```

`PostAsync("api/Account/Login",CreateHttpContent(loginBindingModel))`